# Create second Jinja environmnt in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to create a second Jinja environment to generate LaTeX document.  [This snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/55/) uses [`Flask.create_jinja_environment`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.create_jinja_environment), but I want to use a custom loader: `FileSystemLoader('/path/to/latex/templates')`.  How can I create an env like the snippet but use my custom loader?

> ```
> LATEX_SUBS = (
>     (re.compile(r'\\'), r'\\textbackslash'),
>     (re.compile(r'([{}_#%&$])'), r'\\\1'),
>     (re.compile(r'~'), r'\~{}'),
>     (re.compile(r'\^'), r'\^{}'),
>     (re.compile(r'"'), r"''"),
>     (re.compile(r'\.\.\.+'), r'\\ldots'),
> )
>
> def escape_tex(value):
>     newval = value
>     for pattern, replacement in LATEX_SUBS:
>         newval = pattern.sub(replacement, newval)
>     return newval
>
> texenv = app.create_jinja_environment()
> texenv.block_start_string = '((*'
> texenv.block_end_string = '*))'
> texenv.variable_start_string = '((('
> texenv.variable_end_string = ')))'
> texenv.comment_start_string = '((='
> texenv.comment_end_string = '=))'
> texenv.filters['escape_tex'] = escape_tex
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That snippet uses `create_jinja_environment` so that the templates are loaded from the same place the app templates are.  This is most likely what you want, just create a directory in your app's templates folder with the LaTeX templates.

You can still use `create_jinja_environment` and just replace the loader just like the snippet replaces other attributes on the env.

```
texenv = app.create_jinja_environment()
texenv.loader = FileSystemLoader('/path/to/latex/templates')
```